# Does the Barbarian's Danger Sense feature work against invisible spellcasters?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, class-feature, barbarian

Say a spellcaster under the effect of Greater Invisibility casts a spell at a Barbarian.

Does the [Danger Sense](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/barbarian#DangerSense-54) feature of the Barbarian protect against the spell?

> You have advantage on Dexterity saving throws against effects that you can see, such as traps and spells.

Does the Barbarian have advantage on the saving throw against the spell?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### As long as the effect is projected from the invisible caster, yes

[*Greater invisibility*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/greater-invisibility) states:

> Anything the target is wearing or carrying is invisible as long as it is on the target's person.

When you are casting a spell that projects an effect (like *fireball* or *lightning bolt*) you are not wearing or carrying the effect and that effect is certainly not on the caster's person. This means that the effect becomes visible as the caster casts it. And since you can now see the effect, danger sense applies.

However, if the effect is not projected from the caster, and the DM rules that the effect fulfills the requirement above, then danger sense wouldn't apply since the magical effect itself would be invisible. I have never seen a spell combine with *greater invisibility* in that manner though.

Comment: There are plenty of spells without visible effects (e.g. mind-control or fear-type spells), but they're usually Wisdom saves rather than Dex saves.

Comment: What about Reverse Gravity? Would that qualify?